# How to add AVPlayerViewController to AVPlayerLayer in ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c, avplayer

This is my code, how to add this AVPlayerViewController to AVPlayerLayer and how to hide that layer if we click hideButton.

```
NSString *videoFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:self.string ofType:@"mp3"];
self.avPlayer = [[AVPlayer alloc]initWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:videoFilePath]];
self.avPlayerViewController = [[AVPlayerViewController alloc]init];
self.avPlayerViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(25,375,250,300);
self.avPlayerViewController.player = self.avPlayer;
[self.view addSubview:self.avPlayerViewController.view];
[self.avPlayerViewController.player play];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to play Video in layer, then not required to add AVPlayerController.

The code will be like:

Declare this 2 variable at start:

```
AVPlayer *player;
AVPlayerLayer *playerLayer;
```

Add following method, and call it at `viewDidLoad`

```
-(void)setUpVideoPlayer
{
    AVAudioSession *audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
    NSError *aErr;
    [audioSession setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient withOptions:AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionMixWithOthers error:&aErr];

    NSString *videoFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"videoFileName" ofType:@"videoFileType"];
    NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:videoFilePath];
    player = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:fileURL];
    playerLayer = [AVPlayerLayer playerLayerWithPlayer:player];
    [playerLayer setVideoGravity:AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill];
    playerLayer.frame = // Set Frame whichever you want;

    [self.videoView.layer addSublayer:playerLayer];

    [player seekToTime:kCMTimeZero];
    [player setVolume:0.0f];
    [player setActionAtItemEnd:AVPlayerActionAtItemEndNone];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(playerItemDidReachEnd:)
                                                 name:AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification
                                               object:[player currentItem]];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(playerStartPlaying)
                                                 name:UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification object:nil];
}

-(void)playerStartPlaying
{
    [player play];
}

-(void)playerItemDidReachEnd:(NSNotification*)notification
{
    AVPlayerItem *p = [notification object];
    [p seekToTime:kCMTimeZero]; // Play it again when video ends
}
```

Whenever you want to start video playing, call this method: `[player play]`, whenever you want to hide the layer, just hide the player layer and call `[player pause]` to stop player playing the video.